# JS Higher Order Confusion

Tags: javascript

I am reading JavaScript Alonge and the first higher order function has confused me and looking for some help in understanding the output and why it is so.

```
const repeat = (num, fn) =>
    (num > 0)
        ? (repeat(num - 1), fn), fn(num))
        : undefined

repeat(3, function(n) {
    console.log(`Hello ${n}`)
})
```

The output is:

```
Hello 1
Hello 2
Hello 3
undefined
```

My confusion is that I would expect that it would start at 2 if I was to pass 3 in as the value and it is greater than 0 which would then call repeat again. This is where I get stuck, because of the fact that this seems to me in my thinking that it would start at 2 and need help in how to walk thru this in how the output is what it is.

Thank you

Comment: `repeat(num -1) // 3 - 1`,  however `num` is printed `console.log(3)`

Comment: Yes, it calls `repeat(2, fn)` first. But that doesn't mean that the first output will be the "2", just that it recurses further to `repeat(1, fn)` until `repeat(0, fn)`.

Comment: @Bergi - That is what I needed. Now it makes sense. Please add that so I can mark that as the answer I needed. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would expect that it would start at 2 if I was to pass 3 in as the value and it is greater than 0 which would then call repeat again.

Yes, it calls `repeat(2, fn)` first. But that doesn't mean that the first output will be the "2", just that it recurses further to `repeat(1, fn)` until `repeat(0, fn)`. Only after that, it will call `fn(1)`, after all that `fn(2)`, and only in the end `fn(3)`.

The order would be different if `? (fn(num), repeat(num - 1), fn))` was used.

Answer (score 2):

It might help to expand the ternary operator:

```
const repeat = (num, fn) => {
    if (num > 0) {
        repeat(num -1, fn);
        return fn(num);
    } else {
        return undefined;
    }
}
```

On the 4th line, you can see that `fn` is called with `num`: `fn(num);`.  This line of code will execute for every `num` including `3`.

Also, because the recursive call to `repeat` is made first, the results count up (1 -> 3).  If you were to reverse the order then it would count down (3 -> 1).

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Bergi made a comment on the original question that was of help and when I have that concept in my head I am able to look at the code you added and the content that you describe that has helped me to gather the reasoning behind this. Thank you for taking the time